# implementing CNN - but graph is in russian

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

[image: The network]

so by google translating i figured out

- Вход means input
- Слой means layer.
- Свертка means convolution (this
  must be the number of filters?)
- Шаг means step (this must be stride?)
- субдискр means subdiskr (i guess this is pooling?)

Now my question is how would a 
size 22x256 image result in 6x256 with a 5 filters? 
The filter size (kernel) that i found out results in 6x256 is [17,1] with 1 filter. From layer 1 to layer a kernel size of [1,8] and stride [1,8] is what i found to work. This just does not look like anything on this graph though.

In the paper they wrote this about the layer between 1 and 2

"The second layer allows to reduce the dimensionality of the signal in time, producing a weighted average of the signal over 16 values"

Comment: You can check the explanation of how the output size vary when you perform convolution operations http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the authors:
They told me that they used 1 dimensional CNN.
This Means that the first number is the depth and the second number is the Width:

depth @ width.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)s a clear explanation how the sizes of the inputs vary with proceeding among the layers.

In the input the dimensions that you are giving are 28 wide and 28 height and depth as 1. For filters in layer1 the depth dimension of filter must be equal to the depth of the input. so the dimension of the filter will be 5x5x1, applying one filter the dimension is reduced (due to strides)to produce 14x14x1 dimension activation map, so applying 32 such filters will give you 32 activations maps. Combining all of these 14x14x32 is output of the layer 1 and input to your second layer. Again in second layer you need to apply a filter of dimension 5(width)x5(height)x32(depth) on the layer to produce one activation map of 14x14x1 , stacking all the 64 activation maps give you output dimension of the second layer as 14x14x64 and so on.

In the figure that you posted looks very different in representation. Check the standard ones in your language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
However i know that the input dimension is an image of size
22x256x1 - so not 28x28x1. It says so in the original paper.
I have read the entire article, and i can still not explain how "convolution 5" will take a size 22x256x1 image to size 6x256x1.
"convolution 5" could insinuate the kernel size or the number of filters used?

Comment: Nothing match in the diagram with the translations that you put up. Check something which have standards.

Comment: I agree with this statement. I have contacted the authors of the paper... :)